# starting init: /bin/sh exists but couldn't execute it (error -8)

Tags: linux, bash, kernel, init

I'am building Root filesystem for the *Linux Kernel(6.2.11)*.

I want to compile the *GNU Bash Shell(4.1)* as the init program of the system. I built bash and installed it to the path `/bin/`, then linked `/bin/sh` with `/bin/bash`.

But when I use the command `qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel sysroot/boot/bzImage -hda boot.img -append "root=/dev/sda` to run the system, it displays the message :

```
Starting init: /bin/sh exists but couldn't execute it (error -8)
Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found.
```

[image: screenshot]

May I ask what caused the above problem and how to solve it? Thank you.

Comment: under Fedora 38, it's the case make sure /bin/bash is executable:  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 4  6 févr.  2023 /bin/sh -> bash

Comment: thank you! but it has been set to lrwxrwxrwx.

Comment: errno 8 is ENOEXEC ("Exec format error"), likely wrong architecture (like arm binaries while you're on x86_64  platform with x86_64 kernel)